# Rails app doesn't load a custom theme Javascript listener on a form button

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to using a Bootstrap theme for a Rails project. My Rails imports all the Javascript used by the theme but doesn't use them. To explain lemme get specific about the problem:

A form button when clicked upon pops a modal over the website and upon inspecting all the listeners on the `a` button, I saw that the button has a click listener implemented in "minicart.js"[image showing the implented listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NurZc.png)

the problem is that my Rails app does load the "minicart.js" file but the same form button doesn't have the click listener on it.

[image showing all the files load as assets by my rails app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTMHS.png)
[image showing all the method on my "add to cart" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5Gc4.png)

As you can see, my Rails app doesn't have that method, so when I click on the "add to cart" button the pop-up doesn't appear. The theme has that method/listener but my rails app doesn't even though they have same Javascripts file i.e "minicart.js"

To shed some more light on my project I have added the minicart.js and other custom JS files used by the Bootstrap theme at the path (from root of project) /app/assets/stylesheets/

Next I added those files to Rails' application.js file (which is located at the path from root /app/assets/javascripts/ ) and now my application.js looks like this:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery.flexslider
//= require minicart
//= require easing
//= require popper 
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

the HTML code: I just copied it from the theme's HTML file and pasted it into my project.

i added <%= javascript_include_tag "minicart.js" %> to my html.erb file of that view but still the method doesn't come up in the listener listed for the button in the inspect element section. note : i saved the code in editor and restarted the rails server but it made no difference.

To sum up my problem, I just want the pop to occur when I click on the button in my rails app. Tips for how to proceed to further debug this & any tutorial/reads/articles are appreciated. If you need any other details please feel free to ask.

I'm new to Rails so please bear with me.

Comment: Did you restart the Rails server after making the changes to your code?

Comment: yes, i did restart the server and also saved the changes before restarting the server.

Comment: How did you add minicart.js to your app?

Comment: i added it to my rails project by adding it to my rails'  ''application.js'' file under assets section . i have mention this implicitly above. I did this when i added the line "//= require minicart" to the file.